# How to Use Else If statement in the Script for matching Content

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I would first like to tell you as what I am trying to accomplish from this script.
I am not very familiar with writing scripts, however I have succesfully tested the below script but now when I try to do some changes in it, I get errors

**I want to accomplish the following.**

1. The Loop Should run for `100` Messages only.
2. The Data pointer is skipping Messages, and changing labels of much more than `100` Messages.
3. Label to remain as "Pending" where data is not Grabbed, and change to `Done` where it is grabbed.

```
function GrabFacebookLP() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Pending");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var label2 = GmailApp.createLabel("Done")
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {

var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  subject = message.getSubject(),
  content = message.getPlainBody(),
  date = message.getDate();


// Get the plain text body of the email message
// You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

// Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
if (content) {

  tmp = content.match(/Name :\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var username = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No username';

  tmp = content.match(/Email :\s*([A-Za-z0-9@._-]+)/);
  var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No email';

  tmp = content.match(/Phone number :\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var phone = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'No phone';

  tmp = content.match(/Services :\s*([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var services = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'No Services Chosen/Mentioned';

  ss.appendRow([date, subject, username, email, phone, services]);

} // End if
threads[i].addLabel(label2);
threads[i].removeLabel(label);

} // End for loop

}
```

Comment: Would you please clarify what's not working here.  I understand the messages/threads confusion, but my testing shows your code working fine for processing 100 threads. What i don't understand is what you mean by `where data is not Grabbed`: is there something you're expecting to happen based in the contents of `content`? At the moment every message is processed by your `if(){}` block.

Comment: Thanks for your response Dean,   100 records are being fetched in the spreadsheet, however if there are say a total of 2000 emails with the Label as pending, then 100 records get grabbed in the spreadsheet, However the Label "Pending" changes to "Done" in about 1200 records, thus I miss on about 1900 emails for my next run. I hope I have been able to explain my problem

Comment: You're applying the new label to a thread (which is correct), so even tho you're touching 100 threads, *every message* in those threads gets the label change. Also, you don't do anything in your `if()` test except check that  `message.getPlainBody()` returned something. Two questions: (1) Are you trying to test individual messages? (2) Is your `if()` test supposed to affect which threads get label changes?